# What is the first Listitem being shown on screen in android.

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a `ListView` having many of `List Items`. When the app launches, its first item is the item that becomes the top/first element that we see on screen. When we **scroll-down**, then any of lower  **list-item** becomes the first that we see on screen. Is there anyway to find that which element is on the top of screen at the moment.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why exactly you want to do that ?

Comment: He will have his reasons to do this. This isn't relevant. Just help him to solve his problem! :)

Comment: In `bindView`, i want to get the data of the `ListItem` which is currently at the top of screen and then match it with the previous one, say i stored it in a temp.

Comment: @Radoslav There's reasons why you'd want to do it.  For example, if you have a background process loading data (say from downloading a bitmap) and want to refresh the correct view without the screen flicker from resetting all views you need to know this, because the view at the time of download starting may not be the view its displayed in now.

Comment: I have successfully done this, but I need to find the code-  I remember it was a royal pain in the neck to get it right.  It had to do with tracking of the positions sent to getView, because the ListView always requested them in screen order from top to bottom.  But there were some twists there with regards to scrolling, as it may request one more view at the top than needed.  If I can find the code I'll update with an answer, but I'm not sure I have it anymore.

Comment: I am loading the list using cursor in bindView.

Comment: @GabeSechan it will be a humble help if u find that code. Thnx

Comment: Haven't found it and about to go to bed, but I kind of remember what I did now.  It was based on getFirstVisiblePosition as @nnesterov suggested and storing off some data about the scrolling so I could eliminate a bug where it returned 1 value too low.  Using that function alone left a bug that only occured part of the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you should try to use [getFirstVisiblePosition()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29) method of your ListView. It returns number of first visible item. This number you can  first. Note that it considers partially hidden items as visible.

Comment: in `bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor mCursor)` , I don't have the `ListView`, as i said, m getting all the data via mCursos and then showing it using Custom CursorAdapter.

Comment: Thnx alot, its working exactly i wanted it to work. i used `getListView` in `bindView` to get the `ListView` and then used `getFirstVisiblePosition`...